# Sorting digits in a string or integer?

Tags: ruby, math

I have a combination lock with 10 buttons and I have to press in 4 buttons and then hit Open. Order of the buttons doesn't matter and each button can only be pressed once.

I am sure there are some probability theory and permutation that makes this an easy problem, but I would like to solve it in Ruby.

My thought is to have a while loop and then sort the digits in the counter and if each digit only occur once, then try to insert it in a hash, where I than can get the length of the hash at the end to have number of combinations.

But how can I sort the digits in a string or inter?

Or is there a smarter algorithm for this?

Comment: Could you please improve your question by including the code you have tried to solve the problem?

Comment: All I have is a while loop, where I realise that I somehow need to sort the digits somehow and I am completely blank on how to do that.

Comment: Posting your code would be a good start point. It will make clearer what you are trying to do and will give us a basis to help you

Comment: To sort the digits in a string, you can do something like this: `'2196548'.chars.sort.join` which would return `1245689`.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". You need to try things, then, if you can't figure it show us the minimal code that demonstrates what you tried, and we'll help you fix it. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write a tutorial, or code, for you, which isn't what SO is for. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Comment: This question is a math problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Math

If I understand it right, the "smartest algorithm" is to just calculate [`10 choose 4`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

## Your question

A [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) might be better suited than a `Hash` if you just want to count unique elements.

If you have a string and want to sort the digits, you can use :

```
'4132'.chars.sort
#=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
'4132'.chars.sort.join
#=> "1234"
```

## Alternative

You didn't provide any code, so I'll just write a few hints for an alternative way of calculating it :

- You can describe a button combination with 10 `1` and `0`s.
- Those 10 `1` and `0`s can be seen as a binary number.
- This binary number is between `0` and `2**10-1` (1023)
- You can iterate every number in this range, and convert them to binary (`number.to_s(2)`)
- You can count the number of `1`s to check if 4 buttons are pressed
- You can count the binary numbers that have exactly 4 `1`s

Comment: Downvoter : constructive criticism is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

So, a few things, you said order didn't matter, so we just need the unique combinations. You also said each button could only be pressed once.

You also said you wanted to solve it using ruby, so why write convoluted methods of your own when there's a perfectly simple way?

You seem to be wanting an array though, not a hash.

This will achieve that, but in an array:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].combination(4).to_a
```

This will put it in a hash.

```
combinations_in_hash = Hash.new
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].combination(4).to_a.each_with_index { |x,i| combinations_in_hash[i] = x }
combinations_in_hash
```

But let's say that order of the combination DID matter...

```
combinations_in_hash = Hash.new
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].combination(4).to_a.each_with_index { |x,i| combinations_in_hash[x] = Array.new(x.permutation.to_a) }
combinations_in_hash
```

Or in array form:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].permutation(4).to_a
```

Permutation can combine the combination / permutation effect by passing an argument of the length. Just in case!

That's 5,040 possible combinations. Not too bad!

Comment: Very nice solution. However the correct answer is `10!/(4!(10-4)!)=210`. 5040 looks like if the order matter.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes that's what the first one does, the last one goes in to all permutations, you can see after the second code snippet I went off on a "if the order does matter" meaning 1234 is different thatn 2134. Thanks!